# Nhibernate fetching strategy

Tags: nhibernate

I am using `nservicebus` to handle commands. During a handler i use nhibernate to load my domain object. I use `session.get` for this. Is there way to provide a correct fetching strategy based on which handler I am executing?

I saw hibernate had the option to set a fetching mode on the session before doing the get, but could not locate this in nh3.2

Comment: AIFAIK fetching strategies are set on queries

Comment: That's what I thought.  Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify lazy/eager in your mappings but you will have to use different mappings for each handler then, however why not use a query instead of session.Get and specify the fetching strategies there?

Comment: That was an option as well, but logically I did wanted to simply get my object from the database.  Based on the context some properties would be eagerly loaded.  When I saw the hibernate solution I hoped nhibernate had a similar solution.  Thanks for the reply

Comment: You state that this is possible with Hibernate, could you please specify how ?

Comment: This is possible by using for instance fetch="join" in your many-to-one mapping elements.